# How to count elements by class using list.js

Tags: javascript, list.js

I am using **list.js** for pagination and I am trying to count items in list by category. Here i have a list 7 people, of which : 1 is born in 1970, 2 are born in 1983, and 4 are born 1993. So i am trying to count only people born in 1993 and append the result to a span element. I have only managed to count all items/people in the list using:

```js
var initDB = userList.matchingItems.length;

document.getElementById("iDatabase").innerHTML = initDB;
```

can you please help

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `userList.matchingItems` using JS's `filter` array method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Or you can loop over `userList.matchingItems` and count the ones born in 1993.